# Checking if a mapping attribute is in an XDoc

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Should be easy but the coffee just isn't working this morning.

```
<root>
    <Mappings>
         <Map key="foo" value="bar" />
    </Mappings>

</root>



internal bool MappingExists(KeyValuePair<string,string> targetMap)
        {
            XDocumnet _doc = XDocument.Load(foo.xml)
            var x = //Insert Linq Here?



        }
```

What is the linq statement to check if a Map Node has a key that equals the key in my Dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = from mapElement in doc.Root.Element("Mappings").Elements("Map")
        let keyAttr = map.Attribute("key")
        where keyAttr != null && keyAttr.Value = targetMap.Key
        select mapElement;

return x.Any();
```